# global variable is being identified as null

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a script which similar to this:

foo.php

```
class Foo
{
    function Foo() {
        $Registry = array();
        include 'bar.php';
        $Registry['bar'] = new Bar();
    }
}
```

bar.php

```
class Bar
{
    function Bar() {
        global $Registry;
        print_r(var_dump($Registry));
    }
}
```

but that returns:

```
array
  'Registry' => &null
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it's not identifying the `Registry` variable as an array?

Comment: Take it as an advise given by PHP to drop the use of `global` :-)

Comment: Why do you do this? I'm sure my eyes would hurt if I saw some diagrams of your system architecture :|

Comment: @EmilVikström Diagram? Architecture? ;-)

Comment: I suggest you start watching the [Google Clean Code Talks](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0182.html).

Comment: will do, but the way i'm going about it does make the code super neat. minimal repetitions in the arguments for any new classes. was going to go with using pointers in each class that `Foo` creates, but this feels neater

Comment: You can't be more wrong.

Comment: would falling back to using pointers be better then?

Comment: You need to inject it as parameter either in the class constructor or in the methods that need them.

Comment: @PeeHaa that's what I was doing before. so much for trying to better it through simplicity. Cheers for that though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create $register global and outside of your class

```
$Registry = array();

class Foo
{
  function Foo() {
    global $Registry;
    include 'bar.php';
    $Registry['bar'] = new Bar();
  }
}
```

bar.php

```
class Bar
{
  function Bar() {
    global $Registry;
    print_r(var_dump($Registry));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try global in both functions, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$Registry` does not exist, `Foo->Registry` exists, but that should be access from the object itself.